# How many GET/LIST Requests skip API Server Cache

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-metrics

I understand that LIST/GET requests that specify the revision number as 0 in the request are served from the api server watch cache. This avoids calls to etcd. Kubernetes also now dynamically resizes this cache.

I'd like to understand if there is an inbuilt metric for me to get to see how many read calls are being served from the cache. That would help me find clients that are making calls that don't read from cache.

Comment: I am guessing that this does not exist and that the Kubernetes maintainers would not wish to expose such metrics.